# while() loop's too many results

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I have this code:

```
    $atrr_row = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_attribute WHERE product_id='".$r['product_id']."' and language_id=1");
while($atr=mysql_fetch_array($atrr_row)){
    $attr_n_g = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "attribute_description  WHERE attribute_id  = '" . $atr['attribute_id'] . "' and language_id=1 LIMIT 1"));
    $attr_t.="\t".'<spec name="'.$attr_n_g['name'].'"><![CDATA['.$atr['text'].']]></spec>'."\n";
}
```

It should give results from 2 tables, but it gives normaly firsts product info, then x2 for another product and so on till all product are looped and results are x375 multiplied.

```
Looped data:
First product:
<specs>
<spec name="Age rating">
<![CDATA[18+]]>
</spec>
<spec name="Release date">
<![CDATA[2012]]>
</spec>
<spec name="Online mode">
<![CDATA[No]]>
</spec>
<spec name="Metacritic score">
<![CDATA[75 - 89]]>
</spec>
</specs>

Second product:
<specs>
<spec name="Age rating">
<![CDATA[18+]]>
</spec>
<spec name="Release date">
<![CDATA[2012]]>
</spec>
<spec name="Online mode">
<![CDATA[No]]>
</spec>
<spec name="Metacritic score">
<![CDATA[75 - 89]]>
</spec>
<spec name="Age rating">
<![CDATA[16+]]>
</spec>
<spec name="Release date">
<![CDATA[2011]]>
</spec>
<spec name="Online mode">
<![CDATA[Yes]]>
</spec>
<spec name="Metacritic score">
<![CDATA[90 - 100]]>
</spec>
</specs>
```

And so on... Any ideas?

EDIT

product_attribute table:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItAEi.png

attribute_description table:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kjvzu.png

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do, but I guess a `JOIN` in your query would save you a lot of work as you wouldn't have to query your db in the loop.

Comment: Please post your table structure and an example of desired output.

Comment: There's code missing, but it looks like you're just not resetting `$attr_t` between products.  You append to it forever, so each product's results are also on all products after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would be better of with a JOIN query instead of looping over like this.

```
"SELECT product_attribute.*, attribute_description.name FROM product_attribute LEFT JOIN product_description on product_description.attribute_id = product_attribute.id 
WHERE product_attribute.product_id='".$r['product_id']."'and language_id=1
```

Comment: this should give you all product attributes and their description that have the product id can you try: 
    select product_attrbute.* from product_attribute where product_attribute.product_id=

Answer (score 0):

You are getting everything twice, because `mysql_fetch_array` returns values from the database both with numeric and with string indexes. Using `mysql_fetch_assoc` should solve the problem.